# UILabel.hidden not working

Tags: ios, uilabel, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to get rid of a UILabel, but setting it to hidden, removing it from the superview, or changing the text to "" does not work. I would really appreciate the help. Here is the code:

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
{
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 21))
    label.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2, self.view.bounds.height / 2)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    func getLabelText() -> String
    {
        if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse)
        {
            return ""
        }
        else
        {
            return "Please enable location services."
        }
    }
    label.text = getLabelText()

    print("CHANGED")
    if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse)
    {
        label.hidden = true //<- Problem
        SwiftLoader.show(animated: true)
        print("text: \(label.text)")

        self.tableView.hidden = false

        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    else if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined)
    {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    else
    {
        tableView.hidden = true

        print("112exsw")

        print("Should Present")
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location Access Disabled", message: "In order to use the YidKit minyan finder, please allow location services for YidKit in Settings.",preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let openAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .Default)
            { (action) -> Void in
                if let url = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
                {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
                }
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:
            { (action) -> Void in
        })
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(openAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I am able to successfully hide/unhide a UITableView, but not the UILabel.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely that branch of your if statements is not hit. You can check by setting a breakpoint. You should also check if `label` is `nil` when you are trying to change it.

You would benefit from trying to make your code more concise. Gratuitous nested functions don't help.

Comment: I originally thought that was the case, however everything else in that branch executes.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sending the label to the back before the if statements began, so the table view appeared on top of it and the label wasn't visible.